# Using same observer in multiple fragments and receiving the response only in the visible fragment not the one in backstack

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

I am using RxJava to hit the API's in my android app. The problem here is if use the same observer in two fragments and one fragment is in backstack and the other is in top then the response gets received in both fragments but that's not what i want. The exact case here is:

On a button click a API request is being made using:

```
userModel.hitAPi("12", myList)
```

and observed using:

```
 val obs = userModel.responseAPI.observe(this,
            Observer {
                if (it != null) {
                    if(it.httpCode == 200)
                        Log.e(TAG, "Response: " + it.toString())
                    else{
                        Log.e(TAG, "Response: " + it.toString())
                    }
                }
            })
```

Here's the ViewModel class:

```
 class UserViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val cd = CompositeDisposable()
    val status: MutableLiveData<Boolean>? = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    val responseAPI = MutableLiveData<ResponseAdd>()
    fun hitAPi(userID: String, items: ArrayList<Item>){
        val myModel = ModelAdd("",items,"in",userID,"" )
        cd.add(
            RetrofitHelper.apiInstance.addToCart(myModel)
                .myApiSubscriber(status)
                .subscribe({
                    responseAPI.postValue(it)
                },{
                    it.printStackTrace()
                })
        )
    }

       private fun <T> Single<T>.myApiSubscriber(status: MutableLiveData<Boolean>?): Single<T> {
        return this.doOnSubscribe {
            status?.postValue(true)
            Utils.debugger("PROGRESS ", " doOnSubscribe")
        }.doFinally {
            status?.postValue(false)
            Utils.debugger("PROGRESS ", " doFinally")
        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        cd.dispose()
        super.onCleared()
    }
}
```

now before coming the response if a user switch to another fragment which has the same Observer too then response gets received in that fragment so how do i dispose it off before migrating to another fragment?

Comment: try to use liveData

Comment: @FahadAlotaibi Please check i have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

This question is currently lacking a lot of specifics, feels as though we are talking in pseudocode. What is "same Observer"? Where are these `Observable`s subscribed? Do both `Fragment`s want to receive the result of an API call, but only whichever is currently on screen? Then you will want to separate the API call lifecycle from either `Fragment` and have the `Fragment`s observe something that updates with the result of the API call (such as a database).

When you `.subscribe()` to an `Observable` it returns a `Disposable` object, this is the reference you can call `dispose()` on when the `Fragment` is `onPause()` (or some other appropriate lifecycle).

Comment: same observer means the userModel.responseApi.observe(...) in both fragments and how do i subscribe in this case?

Comment: @CosmicDev This is more a ViewModel question then. The new code makes that part clearer. I think in that case showing how in the Fragments this is being done would be helpful.